# How to get contour lines AND axis labels in a filled contour plot in R

Tags: r, contour, axis-labels

I have found that I can get either contour lines with incorrect axis labels, or correct axis labels and no contour lines. Here is some code that produces the former:

```
x<-c(1:10)
y<-c(1:10)
z<-matrix(x,nrow=length(x),ncol=length(y))
filled.contour(z,plot.axes = { contour(z, nlevels = 20, 
                                     drawlabels = T, axes = FALSE, 
                                     frame.plot = FFALSE, add = TRUE);
                 axis(1); axis(2) } )
```

And here is some that produces the latter:

```
x<-c(1:10)
y<-c(1:10)
z<-matrix(x,nrow=length(x),ncol=length(y))
filled.contour(x,y,z,plot.axes = { contour(z, nlevels = 20, 
                                     drawlabels = T, axes = FALSE, 
                                     frame.plot = FFALSE, add = TRUE);
                 axis(1); axis(2) } )
```

The difference is that I specified the x and y values. Does anybody know how to get both?

Thnaks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot `x` and `y` in the `contour` call:

```
x<-c(1:10)
y<-c(1:10)
z<-matrix(x,nrow=length(x),ncol=length(y))
filled.contour(x,y,z,plot.axes = { contour(x,y,z, nlevels = 20, 
                                 drawlabels = TRUE, axes = FALSE, 
                                 frame.plot = FALSE, add = TRUE);
             axis(1); axis(2) } )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Pascal! I couldn't figure that out!